# Convert a SHP file set to a categorised ASC raster with Qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, maxent

I have a shapefile with regolith (soil) data that I would like to use as a categorised raster (say 007_1ASC) in Maxent.

The regolith data is in the following files:

007_1.cpg 
007_1.dbf 
007_1.prj
007_1.sbn
007_1.sbx
007_1.shp
007_1.shx

Using Qgis, how can I get this into an ASC file with categorised data?

Comment: When I look at the attribute table the columns are labelled:

gid, regid, regcode, narrative

The regcode is the value that I need to be reflected in my categorised data.

When I I go into the 'rasterize' dialogue I can select 'Attribute field' set to 'gid' or 'regid'.

How can I select 'regcode'?

Comment: I think the answer may be to change the string values for the 'regcode' to an int value. I will try this and update the question.